# while loop [: too many arguments

Tags: bash

After parsing a json object

```
{
  "result" : {
    "period" : 1,
    "unit" : "day",
    "type" : "database",
    "relevant_date" : "2018-07-10 00:00:00",
    "load_date" : "2018-07-10 00:00:00",
    "created" : "2018-07-05 12:23:07",
    "metrics" : { }
  },
  "errorMessage" : "",
  "status" : "OK"
}
```

using bash and python

```
curl -s 'url' | python -c "import sys, json; print json.load(sys.stdin)['result']['load_date']"
```

and getting the following result

```
2018-07-10 00:00:00
```

I try to check if this value matches a predefined one and if it doesn't call sleep.

```
while [ $(curl -s 'url' | python -c "import sys, json; print json.load(sys.stdin)['result']['load_date']") != '2018-07-10 00:00:00' ]
do
  sleep 5s
done
```

But get `[: too many arguments`

Does anybody know why and how to correct it?

Comment: The semicolon at the end, is it a typo?

Comment: @Marcus Yes. Removed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to quote the output of your `$(...)` pipeline, because the output contains whitespace.  For example, consider this:

```
$ [ $(echo this is a test) = "this is a test" ] && echo "it matched"
-bash: [: too many arguments
```

Versus this:

```
$ [ "$(echo this is a test)" = "this is a test" ] && echo "it matched"
it matched
```

Answer (score 0):

This is much easier with `jq`:

```
filter='.result.load_date | select(. == "2018-07-10 00:00:00")'
until curl -s 'url' | jq -e "$filter" > /dev/null; do
  sleep 5s
done
```

The filter outputs the load date if it matches the desired date, and nothing otherwise. The `-e` option gives `jq` a non-zero exit status when there is no output, which causes the `until` loop to continue until `jq` produces a matching date.

Comment: I know. I just don't have the possibility of installing it. Can only work with default software.